# When pushing a button inside a partial view, parent form is validated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

In a MVC 5 application, I have a partial view with a button to submit some information. But when I push that button the parent form is validated, making all the validating errors displayed. All I want is that only the validated fields in the partial view are executed with no interaction with the parent form.

Code update (partial view, UploadFile):

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Upload","File")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="photo">Photo:</label>
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" />

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Code parent form:

```
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoriaId, "CategoriaId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("CategoriaId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoriaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Titulo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Titulo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Titulo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descripcion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descripcion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descripcion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Precio, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Precio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Precio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>


        @Html.Partial("UploadFile")
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your code, it's hard to answer without seeing your code.

Comment: I have inserted the code

Comment: You have nested forms which is invalid html

Comment: Yes. That's was the problem. I'm just starting programming with MVC so I have old ways programming in standard ASP.NET. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a `<form>` tag inside the partial view and you put `@Html.Partial("UploadFile")` inside `@using (Html.BeginForm())` block like below

```
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    ....
    ....
    ....

    @Html.Partial("UploadFile")
}
```

It will be rendered as nested forms like this

```
<h2>Create</h2>
<form>
    .... 
    ....
    ....

    <form action="/File/Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <label for="photo">Photo:</label>
        <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" />

        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
</form>
```

which is invalid html. You need to move `@Html.Partial("UploadFile")` outside of `@using (Html.BeginForm())` block

```
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ....
    ....
    ....
}

@Html.Partial("UploadFile")
```

Answer (score 1):

This may cause due to nested form.

> Make sure that child form is not nested inside another form.

the HTML specs forbid nested forms.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ..
}
@Html.Partial("UploadFile") // place it outside of main form
```

As partial view contain another form you need to place it outside of main form anotherwise it will be nesting(**HTML specs forbid nested forms**)